# Is There A Way to Dynamically Set the Styled Component Prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components

I am trying to create a function as such to dynamically set the value and the property of a css block for styled components

```
function ifElementDisplayProp(
    element: string,
    prop: string,
    fallback?: string
): FlattenSimpleInterpolation {
    if (theme?.[element]?.[prop]) {
        const value = theme[element][prop]
        return css`
            ${prop}: ${value};
        `
    } else {
        return css`
            ${prop}: ${fallback};
        `
    }
}
```

The imputs for this function could be  `"Button", "font-size", "22px"`
This function would be called in the styled block as such:

```
const StyledButton = styled.button`
    ${ifElementDisplayProp('Button', 'font-size', '22px')}
`
```

Is there something that would make the first function work properly. I am getting the following error when hovering over the "$" for the css property name:

```
} expected ts-styled-plugin(9999)
```

Comment: Why to reinvent the wheel? You have an entire section in SC docs for util libraries: https://styled-components.com/ecosystem, one example is https://github.com/diegohaz/styled-tools which has such API.

Comment: @DennisVash I am less of a fan of installing libraries when I only need one piece from them but I will look into those examples they seem interesting.

Comment: @DennisVash I looked it over and say I do want to reinvent the wheel this way do you know why I am getting this warning from TS?

Comment: I guess because you need to configure it to support macros or whatever this syntax is called, in your case I would look for references in those libraries

Comment: Its called Tagged Templates: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#tagged_templates